# kubernetes egress policy to allow UDP

Tags: kubernetes, sybase, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

Trying to run application in kubernetes which need to access Sybase DB from with in the Pod . I have the below egress Network policy which should allow all .The sybase db connection is getting created but its getting closed soon(Connection Closed Error) . Sybase docs say

*Firewall software may filter network packets according to network port. Also, it is common to disallow UDP packets from crossing the firewall*.

My question is do i need to explicitly specify something for UDP or should nt the egress  Allow all ( {}) take care of this ?

> NetWork Policy

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: spring-app-network-policy
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      role: spring-app
  ingress:
    - {}
  egress:
    - {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
```

Comment: Where do you deploy the kubernetes cluster? By default all traffic should be allowed if you don't specify network policy. Does the same error appears without Network Policy applied?

Comment: You are right . The issue was i was using spring cloud which internally spawn new applications/pods with  different name and the policy was nt get applied .i got this working  by adding network policy for the newly spawned apps

Answer (score 2):

The issue was using spring cloud which internally deployed new pods with different names and the policy was not applied. It's working by adding network policy for the newly deployed applications.

Comment: why did u copy my comment and put as answer?

Comment: It is added as a community wiki- community cannot vote on this post (upvote) so there is no reputation added to my account and it was added for better visibility so others can benefit from it in case they face same issues.

Comment: oh ok sorry i  m not ble to upvote it . please edit ur answer  ll do.